# Как принять новые поля формы в php?

Tags: php, javascript, post, form

[[image]]

[
есть уже добавленные строки : skill_name и skill_value ,при нажатии "+" добавляется еще одна такая же строка.Как при отправке проверить, если это новая строка(или их несколько),то тогда их добавляем в бд]

Comment: вы можете попробовать добавлять таким полям к имени _new, далее уже перебирая их на бекенде, вы можете смотреть, например на совпадение строки с _new и тем самым помечать поле как новое

Comment: вопрос актуален